# Security settings of all resources in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops

I am having the list of security settings of resources in Azure DevOps but not everything. Could someone please share the document which has all the resource settings of Azure DevOps so that If we are onboarding someone in ADO with scrum master role.Below are the activities he can perform and what level of access modification we need to do in ADO.

Below is one example :

Create work item
Modify work item
Delete work item
Customize the team board
Customize the process .
Create sprints
Customize sprint board
View/create dashboard.
Create queries  .
Access for shared queries
etc ( whatever you can think of as a scrum master)

Answer (score 0):

> Could someone please share the document which has all the resource
>   settings of Azure DevOps.

Azure Devops use access level, groups, security roles... to manage the permissions, so there doesn't exist one single document has all the resource settings you want. You can check the topic [Grant or restrict permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/project-admin-tutorial?view=azure-devops#grant-or-restrict-permissions) to get details about how to manage permissions in Azure Devops Service.

> so that If we are onboarding someone in ADO with scrum master
>   role.Below are the activities he can perform and what level of access
>   modification we need to do in ADO

For the permissions in your example, you need to give the user basic access level +Project Admin. See [Prerequisites](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/queries/set-query-permissions?view=azure-devops#prerequisites) of Shared Query, the user should be at least Basic role and Project Admin to create/delete/edit/save Shared query:

[image]

(Organization Settings=>Users=>Manage User)